# Chart is getting cut. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visualization

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRAj0.jpg) I dont know what am i doing wrong,I have tried using every combination between viewport and viewbox,the chart on the lowerside remains cut,Any help on this is much appreciated,I have just started learning js.Sorry if its a stupid question.I am also attaching scrrenshot just in case,I am having problem with that black bubble chart.I am using eclipse and d3.js library for visualisation and deploying through tomcat 8.0 server.

```
!(function(){
"use strict"

var width,height
var chartWidth, chartHeight
var margin
var svg = d3.select("#svg1").append("svg")
var chartLayer = svg.append("g").classed("chartLayer", true)

main()

function main() {
    var range = 100
    var data = {
        nodes:d3.range(0, range).map(function(d){ return {label: "l"+d 
,r:~~d3.randomUniform(8, 28)()}}),
        links:d3.range(0, range).map(function(){ return 
{source:~~d3.randomUniform(range)(), target:~~d3.randomUniform(range)()} })        
    }

    setSize(data)
    drawChart(data)    
}

function setSize(data) {
    width = document.querySelector("#svg1").clientWidth
    height = document.querySelector("#svg1").clientHeight

    margin = {top:0, left:0, bottom:0, right:0 }


    chartWidth = width - (margin.left+margin.right)
    chartHeight = height - (margin.top+margin.bottom)

    svg.attr("width", width).attr("height", height)


    chartLayer
        .attr("width", chartWidth)
        .attr("height", chartHeight)
        .attr("transform", "translate("+[margin.left, margin.top]+")")


}

function drawChart(data) {

    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
        .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.index }))
        .force("collide",d3.forceCollide( function(d){return d.r + 1 
}).iterations(24) )
        .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
        .force("center", d3.forceCenter(chartWidth / 2, chartWidth / 2))
        .force("y", d3.forceY(0))
        .force("x", d3.forceX(0))

    var link = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "links")
        .selectAll("foo")
        .data(data.links)
        .enter()
        .append("line")
        .attr("stroke", "transparent")

    var node = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "nodes")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(data.nodes)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d){  return d.r })
        .call(d3.drag()
            .on("start", dragstarted)
            .on("drag", dragged)
            .on("end", dragended));    


    var ticked = function() {
        link
            .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

        node
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
    }  

    simulation
        .nodes(data.nodes)
        .on("tick", ticked);

    simulation.force("link")
        .links(data.links);    



    function dragstarted(d) {
        if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
        d.fx = d.x;
        d.fy = d.y;
    }

    function dragged(d) {
        d.fx = d3.event.x;
        d.fy = d3.event.y;
    }

    function dragended(d) {
        if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
        d.fx = null;
        d.fy = null;
    } 

}
}());
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Basic Bootstrap Template</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="d3V4/d3.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="d3V4/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="d3-legend.js"></script>

<style>
<svg id="svg2" width="500" height="500" viewBox="-30 0 550 500 " ></svg>
<script src="myscript.js" defer></script>
<svg id="svg1" width="600" height="500"></svg>
<script src="myscript2.js" defer></script>
<svg id="svg3" width="750" height="450" viewBox="-295 0 680 550 "></svg>
<script src="myscript3.js" defer></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: put it in a jsfiddle, or at least give or put the other code for this, cause I cannot help you if you do not.

Comment: Other code meaning which code?

Comment: the html and css that accompany this body of javascript.

Comment: I have added this html script ,there is no seperate css file.the above javascript is myscript2.js

Comment: I shall put that into a js fiddle if possible.

Comment: ok, take the source code from your file, then paste it.

Comment: Ok its working now,removed viewbox parameter and added again with same parameters as viewport.